# Browser zoom is causing weird behavior select box

Tags: html, css

I got a question regarding browser zoom and my select box. I have created a custom select box with the current HTML and CSS code ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qs8q3nya/)):

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.custom-select select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 5px 8px 10px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  color: #0085c8;
}
.custom-select.svg > svg.dropdown-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/solid-line-essential-ui-icon-set/512/essential_set_down-16.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  color: #0085c8;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select svg">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="Volkswagon Polo">Volkswagon Polo</option>
  </select>
  <svg class="dropdown-button"></svg>
</div>
```

Whenever you scale down your browser to for example 75% I get the following situation:
[image]

Where the word POLO is cutoff. What am I doing wrong? This should not be zooming sensitive right? Can you set CSS styling to specific zoom levels?

**--EDIT**
Increasing the width is not an option due to the fact that the select is been placed inside a div with a maximum width of `150px`

Comment: You could just change the width of the .custom-select class to 150px for instance.

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig that would work if I can increase the width. But I can't

Comment: What do you mean you can't do that?

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig The dropdown will be placed inside a div and this div can be max`100px` wide. Therefore I can not increase the size of the custom select class or it will overflow

Comment: a band-aid solution would be to remove the padding/margin to the left-side of the options

Comment: @NachoDawg That would be nice despite the fact that within webkit browsers it is not possible to style the `option` object other than setting the  background-color and color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with giving auto width to your custom select box.

```css
.custom-select
{
    position: relative;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden
}
.custom-select select{
 width:auto;
 padding: 8px 5px 8px 10px; 
 height:36px;
 border: 1px solid #cacaca;
 color: #0085c8;   
}
.custom-select.svg > svg.dropdown-button
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/solid-line-essential-ui-icon-set/512/essential_set_down-16.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    pointer-events: none;
   border: 1px solid #cacaca;
   color: #0085c8;
   display:inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select svg">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="Volkswagon Polo">Volkswagon Polo</option>
  </select>
  <svg class="dropdown-button"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: "Polo" is still cut out here

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig run snippet and check properly.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey good solution but this will overflow my specified width of `100px`. Because it is been placed inside a `div` containing a maximum width of `100px`

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I am running the snippet properly and it's not working

Comment: @Rotan075 I have updated snippet, please check once.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Your updated solutions works! Thank you! Using `overflow:hidden` and `width:auto` did the trick!

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Removed the down vote and changed it to up vote :)